# if/else statement inside .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Let's say I have this code which gets the latest posts via ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: loadmore,
    data: {lastid: lastid,mode:'latest'},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(json){
      //some code
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      //some code
    }
  });
```

How do I change the content of the data? Here's my try but something failed.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: loadmore,
    if($('.postlist').hasClass('best'))
      data: {lastrank: lastrank,mode: 'best'},
    else
      data: {lastid: lastid,mode:'latest'},
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(json){
      //some code
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      //some code
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ternary operator:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: loadmore,
    data: ($('.postlist').hasClass('best') ?
      {lastrank: lastrank,mode: 'best'} :
      {lastid: lastid,mode:'latest'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(json){
      //some code
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      //some code
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ?: (ternary operator) operator:

```
data: ($('.postlist').hasClass('best')) ?
      {lastrank: lastrank,mode: 'best'} : 
      {lastid: lastid,mode:'latest'},
```